# Prove that $\sup{\alpha A} = \alpha \sup{A}$

Tags: calculus

> Prove that if $\alpha > 0$, then $\sup{\alpha A} = \alpha \sup{A}$ and $\inf{\alpha A} =\alpha \inf{A}$.

I think this can easily be proven using induction using the fact that $\sup(A+B) = \sup{A}+\sup{B}$ and $\inf(A+B) = \inf{A}+\inf{B}$. So we prove it for all $\alpha \neq 0$. Is this the way to approach solving this?

Comment: Induction only works for natural numbers. We're working with real numbers here.

Comment: Also, even for natural numbers $\alpha$, this strategy is flawed, because $2A$ and $A+A$ are not the same set, for example! (Try it with $A=\{0,1\}$.)

Comment: @GregMartin How aren't they the same?

Comment: Really, try it with $A=\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Induction has nothing to do with this.

Hint: the map $x\mapsto \alpha x$ is increasing if $\alpha>0$.

Further hints as spoilers.

Spoiler 1

> Let $s=\sup A$; then, for each $x\in A$, $x\le s$; therefore, for each $x\in A$, $\alpha x\le\alpha s$. Hence $\alpha s$ is an upper bound for $\alpha A$

Spoiler 2

> Suppose $t$ is an upper bound for $\alpha A$. Then $\alpha^{-1}t$ is an upper bound for $A$ (why?). Therefore $\alpha^{-1}t\ge s$ and so $t\ge \alpha s$.

Comment: So then we know that $\sup((\alpha+1)(A)) > \sup(\alpha A)$. How does that help?

Comment: @user19405892 Do you know the definition of $\alpha A$?

Comment: @ZacharySelk It is $\alpha A = \{\alpha a | a \in A\}$.

Comment: @user19405892 Use that definition, along with definition of $\sup$

Comment: We have $\sup{\alpha A} = x > y \in \alpha A$.

Answer (score 0):

First note that $\sup A = -\infty$ if and only if $A=\emptyset$. Hence, this case is trivial as $\alpha \emptyset = \emptyset$.

Let us assume that $A$ is bounded, i.e. $\sup A < \infty$.

Let $a\in A$, then holds

$$ \alpha a \leq \alpha \sup A. $$

Hence, $\sup \alpha A \leq \alpha \sup A.$

Let now $\epsilon >0$, then there exists $a_{\epsilon}\in A$ such that

$$ \sup A - \epsilon \leq a_{\epsilon}.$$

Therefore,

$$ \alpha \sup A - \alpha \epsilon \leq \alpha a_{\epsilon} \leq \sup \alpha A.$$

Taking the limit for $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ gives us

$$ \alpha \sup A \leq \sup \alpha A. $$

Putting the two inequalities together yields

$$ \alpha \sup = \sup \alpha A. $$

In the case where $\sup A = \infty$, there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq A$ such that $x_n \rightarrow \infty$. However, then $(\alpha x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \alpha A$ and $\alpha x_n \rightarrow \infty$, thus $\sup \alpha A= \infty$ and this proves the claim.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume $$\alpha \sup A \gt \sup \alpha A$$

By definition, there is $a \in A$, such that $$\alpha a \gt \sup \alpha A$$

this can not be true because we know that $$\alpha a \le \sup \alpha A$$

I think you can use similar approach for other proofs.

Comment: How do you know that $\alpha a > \sup{\alpha A}$ and not $\alpha a \geq \sup{\alpha A}$?

Comment: This is because my assumption that $\alpha \sup A \gt \sup \alpha A$. If my assumption is not correct, the $\alpha \sup A \le \sup \alpha A$. We know it cannot be less. So it should be "equal".

Comment: But the supremum of $A$ doesn't have to be in $A$.

Comment: but any number smaller than  $\sup A$ should be in A.

Comment: Right, but how does that still imply $\alpha a > \sup{\alpha A}$?

Comment: What about if I cannot find it? Will it lead to $\alpha a \le \sup \alpha A$. for all $a \in A$

Comment: All I am saying is that your claim that $a \in A$ is not necessarily true.